# Dynamic clip effect not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I found this video and I'm trying to implement the dual image reveal feature into one of my client's websites. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyEJvujXAwM&index=5&t=55s&list=PL9eBC8yKMyol9Bl9jefAiZL0v4IWi3QEA

The image reveal essentially positions an image underneath another then uses the clip dynamically using CSS and jquery to make it so the picture will clip and reveal the image behind it.

The site will have several categories that when clicked automatically load the category's pictures into a slideshow. If you click any of the pictures in the slideshow a modal will pop up of that image with another image positioned underneath it. As of now my my clip function is working but for some reason the clip is starting at 340px(thus making it so the full image shows because the image is 280px) as opposed to 0px and then moving in a range from 0-280px. Can someone check my code and see what's wrong?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

              <div class = "reveal">
                  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
                  <img  src="" id = "mimg" class = "modalimg" width = "280px" height = "280px">
                  <img  src="" id = "mimg2" class = "modalimg2" width = "280px" height = "280px">
                  <div class = "activator" onmousemove = "reveal(event)"></div>
                </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class = "img1">
                <img src = "http://www.defenders.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/tiger-dirk-freder-isp.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt = "BlackProPix Photography" height = "160px" width = "176px">
                <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt = "BlackProPix Photography" height = "160px" width = "176px">
            </div>

function reveal(event) {
            event.target.previousElementSibling.style.clip = "rect(0px, "+(event.clientX-event.target.offsetLeft)+"px, 280px, 0px)";
        }

.reveal{
    width: 280px;
    height: 280px;
    border:#000 1px solid;
    float:left;
    margin:24px;
}
.reveal > img{
    position:absolute;
}
.reveal > .img2{
    clip:rect(0px, 140px, 280px, 0px); /* top, right, bottom, left */ 
}
.reveal > .activator{
    position:absolute;
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
    opacity:0;
    cursor: e-resize;
}
```